# Using Lagrange Thm to prove order of subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'd like to answer the following question.

> Suppose that I have a group, namely $G$, which has an order of $14$. I
>   want to prove that $G$ must have  a subgroup that has order $7$.

So by assumption, I think that there exists a subgroup of order $1,2,7, 14$, but obviously that is no proof, rather an intuition.

By Lagrange Theorem, if $K$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then the order of $K$ divides the order of $G$. In particular, $|G|=|K|[G:K]$.

I'm not so sure that Lagrange Theorem really helps us solve this problem.

How do I proceed with a proof? Any reading material or examples would be great.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem doesn't help.  It says that $1, 2, 7, 14$ are the only possible subgroup sizes, not that one actually exists.  There is a theorem that says that if a prime divides a group, then there is an element of that order.  Do you have that theorem?

Comment: You might also use Sylow's theorems.

Comment: Are you referring to Cauchy's Theorem? I will look into Sylow's Theorems also.

Answer (score 2):

- If $G$ has an element $g$ of order $14$, then $\langle g^2 \rangle$ is a subgroup of order $7$.
- If $G$ has an element $g$ of order $7$, then $\langle g \rangle$ is a subgroup of order $7$.
- Otherwise, all nontrivial elements of $G$ have order $2$.
  Let $a,b \in G \setminus \{e\}$, with $a\ne b$. Then $ab$ has order $2$ and so $ab=ba$.
  Therefore, the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ has order $4$, which contradicts Lagrange's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Since $7$ is a prime number, Cauchy's theorem says that $G$ has some element whose order is $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to stay away from big theorems and actually use only Lagrange.

Take a non-trivial element $a$. Its order is either $2$, $7$ or $14$. If it's $7$, you're done. If it's $14$, you're also done by considering $a^2$.

The only problem is when every element has order $2$, in which case it is classic that $G$ is abelian, since $$abab=e\implies ba=(aa)ba(bb)=a(abab)b=ab$$

Now when $G$ is abelian, there actually can't be more than one element of order $2$, because if there were two of them they would generate a subgroup of order $4$, which doesn't divide $14$.